# Rock, paper, scissors in python Tips to make it better

Tags: python

I've just learned some Python recently, I wrote a script for Rock,paper,scissors.
I just want any tips to make it better, and how to be better in future.
I listened to some tips and added the score counter and fixed some things.
Am I doing it right or what?
The script is:

```
import random
import time
print('Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors')
print(' '*25) 
wins = 0
loses = 0
draws = 0
point= int(input('How many rounds do you want to play?'))
list = ['r','p','s']
for x in range (1,(point+1)):
    computer = random.choice(list)
    human=str(input('Choose (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors?'))
    if human == computer:
        draws = draws + 1
        print('''Human: {}         Computer: {}           A draw
        Wins = {}   Loses = {}   Draws = {}'''.format(human,computer,wins,loses,draws))
        print(' '*25)
    elif human == 'r' and computer == 'p':
        loses = loses + 1
        print('''Human: ROCK       Computer: PAPER        Computer wins
        Wins = {}   Loses = {}   Draws = {}'''.format(wins,loses,draws))
        print(' '*25)
    elif human == 'r' and computer == 's':
        wins = wins + 1
        print('''Human: ROCK       Computer: SCISSORS     Human wins
        Wins = {}   Loses = {}   Draws = {}'''.format(wins,loses,draws))
        print(' '*25)
    elif human == 'p' and computer == 's':
        loses = loses + 1
        print('''Human: PAPER      Computer: SCISSORS     Computer wins 
        Wins = {}   Loses = {}   Draws = {}'''.format(wins,loses,draws))
        print(' '*25)
    elif human == 'p' and computer == 'r':
        wins = wins + 1
        print('''Human: PAPER      Computer: ROCK        Human wins
        Wins = {}   Loses = {}   Draws = {}'''.format(wins,loses,draws))
        print(' '*25)
    elif human == 's' and computer == 'p':
        wins = wins + 1
        print('''Human: SCISSORS   Computer: PAPER    Human wins
        Wins = {}   Loses = {}   Draws = {}'''.format(wins,loses,draws))
        print(' '*25)
    elif human == 's' and computer == 'r':
        loses = loses + 1
        print('''Human: SCISSORS   Computer: ROCK     Computer wins
        Wins = {}   Loses = {}   Draws = {}'''.format(wins,loses,draws))
        print(' '*25)
    else:
        print('Error')
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ perhaps?

Comment: More appropriate for codereview. But the obvious answer is that long if/elif chain. That's code duplication, which is a bad thing. Try to find a way to eliminate it.

Comment: you should use some object oriented ways of coding: if you create an object "Score Comparer" and another one "Result Displayer", the code would be better because more robust. remember to use a little "copy & paste" as possible while coding, Python offers many way to avoid that

Comment: This belongs in Stackexchange's codereview.